# Choosing existing banking information in iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect

I had to re-request a contract in iTunes Connect. When doing so I need to set the Bank Info again but it wouldn't let me use the existing bank account which I have entered in ITC. When I press "Set Up" under Bank Info it gives me two things. First I get the "Current Bank Account" which I can view or edit (I don't want to edit anything since the account is correct). Second, I get "Select a different Bank Account" option with an empty drop-down list (since I don't have other bank accounts specified). What I would like to do is just comfirm the existing bank account, but when I press Save it says "You must make a change in order to Save". The only button I *can* press is Cancel which brings me back to the previeus page showing my contract overview where I can see that the contract has a "Pending Bank" status. So it seems somewhat of a paradox. Am I missing something here?

Thanx!

Comment: It must be the problem in iTunes Connect, cause I'm struggling with that for couple of days no. I've written a report to Apple but haven't got any response from them yet.

Comment: Alas, this question is closed, so I can't add an answer. I managed to work around this problem just now by going to edit the bank information and simply sticking an extra space at the end of my company name and submitting the form (which fixed the "pending bank" problem on the agreements page).

Comment: I fixed it by ading a second Bank account - then the first one worked. Strange but it works.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the issue was resolved by it self. I read somwhere else that others have had the same expirience. Weird...

Comment: I had the same. Just waited a few minutes (15 or so) in the 'pending bank' status, and it automatically became active. It's sad that these kind of sh*t happen, because i've wasted 15 minutes disturbing workmates, finding apple support, and doing useless actions

Comment: I did not expect this 'issue' to exist since almost 4 years ago, now at least they inform you with the message 

Note: Banking update in progress, your changes should be reflected within 24 hours.
You will not be able to make any changes until your update completes processing.

Comment: after 15 minutes (from starting to deal with itunes connect to re-request, and the only thing left was the bank account) it was resolved by it self.
just refresh and go to the main page of Agreements, Tax, and Banking

Comment: This still happens..it now says the slightly more ambiguous "We’ll transfer the banking information from the agreement to this agreement. You don’t need to do anything else — your banking information will update automatically for your other active agreements." - cleared itself up in about 5 minutes and new contract is in effect.

Comment: I'm having the same issue! Can't believe apple never fixes this kind of issues and never displays meaningful error messages atleast

Comment: Same. Just happened. Waited 10 minutes, logged out and back in and it's updated without having to change/add bank.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue here (for the second time!). I solved it creating another bank account and then changed back to my default one.

Comment: even this way doesnt work for me. How did you do it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I've contacted Apple support to solve it. As usual in Apple case they haven't give me any feedback about the nature of the problem, they just fixed the contract for me.

I think you should try doing the same, although it takes quite a long - around 1 week in my case.

Comment: I am curious about how you actually contacted Apple. The "Contact Us" link in iTunes Connect is just a maze of FAQ's with no real option of submitting a question. And I couldn't find an email address or phone number either.

Comment: Select 'Banking and Tax' and under the explain, it says something like "if you still want to contact us".. that reveals the form.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Contacted Apple and they fixed it but other people said they had to wait for 2-3 days and the problem solved itself. I hope this helps:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3148755?start=0&tstart=0